# How to use pdfmake with fastify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fastify, pdfmake

[PDFMake](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/getting-started/server-side/) has this method for streaming a generated PDF document :

```
const pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition, options);
pdfDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('document.pdf'));  // send to output stream
pdfDoc.end();
```

And [fastify](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Reply/#streams) has this to stream things :

```
fastify.get('/streams', function (request, reply) {
  const fs = require('fs')
  const stream = fs.createReadStream('some-file', 'utf8')
  reply.header('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
  reply.send(stream)    // send from input stream
})
```

How are those two working together? Preferably, PDFMake should directly stream through fastify and not buffer the entire PDF before sending it.

For reference, with [Koa](https://koajs.com/) (or [Express](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res)), I would simply do :

```
app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  const pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition, options);

  res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/pdf');
  res.setHeader('content-disposition', req.headers['content-disposition'] || 'inline');
  res.status(200);

  pdfDoc.pipe(res);
  pdfDoc.end(); 
});
```

However, I cannot do `reply.send(pdfDoc)`.

---

#### Update

Since [PDFKit](https://github.com/foliojs/pdfkit)'s `PDFKit.PDFDocument` type seems to be a readable stream, I have tried

```
fastify.get('/streams', function (request, reply) {
  const pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition, options);

  reply.header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
  reply.header('content-disposition', 'inline');
  reply.send(pdfDoc);   // "Failed to load PDF document"
})
```

I also tried [PDFKit](https://github.com/foliojs/pdfkit)'s solution of using [`blob-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blob-stream) :

```
fastify.get('/streams', function (request, reply) {
  const pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition, options);
  const stream = pdfDoc.pipe(blobStream());

  reply.header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
  reply.header('content-disposition', 'inline');
  reply.send(stream);   // "Failed to load PDF document"

  pdfDoc.end();
})
```

There are no errors except in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my current solution :

```
fastify.get('/pdf', async (request, reply) => {
  const pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(...getDocumentDefinition(request));

  const buffer = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const chunks = [];
    const stream = new Writable({
       write: (chunk, _, next) => {
          chunks.push(chunk);
          next();
       }
    });
    stream.once('error', (err) => reject(err));
    stream.once('close', () => resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks)));

    pdfDoc.pipe(stream);
    pdfDoc.end();
  });

  reply.type('application/pdf').code(200).send(buffer);
})
```